# HTML, CSS, JS:How to make a div respond once having reached a certain coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I am currently coding a video game, and I want my div circle to stop once it has reached a certain area, say, 30, -30, I want it to stop, or give the user an alert.
I have used a assortment of @keyframes, divs, getElementById, So and so forth. I have also created a board in which the ball moves around via keyboard.
Oh, and before you see the code, just know I'm a young kid so sorry if the solution is simple.
Here is my code so far:

```js
var dice = document.getElementById("dice").addEventListener("click", numChange);

function numChange() {
  alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1));
}

let circle = document.querySelector(".man");
let moveBy = 25;

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  circle.style.position = "absolute";
  circle.style.left = 0;
  circle.style.top = 0;
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.board {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  //grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 10vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 10vw);
  color: grey;
  background-color: grey;
  font-family: Dosis, sans-serif;
}

.link {
  font-family: Dosis, san-serif;
}

* {
  font-family: "Dosis", "san-serif";
}

.square:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.square:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.square:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.square:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.square:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.square:nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.square:nth-child(12) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.square:nth-child(13) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.square:nth-child(14) {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.square:nth-child(15) {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 1;
  }

.square:nth-child(16) {
    //grid-row: 2;
    //grid-column: 1;
  }

 Demo Specific Style
.board {
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.square {
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.man {
  position: absolute;
  top: 410px;
  right: 380px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black; 
}
/* .man2 {  */ 
  position: absolute;
  top: 410px;
  right: 545px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: up 9s infinite;
  animation-delay: 8.5s;
}
 .man3 { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 545px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: right2 9s infinite;
  animation-delay: 17s;
}


@keyframes right {
  from {right: 240px;}
  to {right: 540px;}
  0% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  75% {
 
    background-color: black;
  }
  100%{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
  }
  }


  


.dice {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 440px;
  top: 320px;
}

numChange {
  
}
/*.inside-board {*/
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 145px;
  right: 290px;
}
```

```html
<div class="man"></div.
<div class="man2" id="seen"></div>
<div class="man3" id="Seen"></div>
<div class="dice" id="dice"></div>
<div class="inside-board"></div>

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="https://cdpn.io/Dims09/debug/mdOXGrQ/xnMabmBRoVjr">
  <h3 class="link">Back</h3>
</a>
<div class="board">
  
  <div class="square">START</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">guardian</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">LAVA</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">NATIVE</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">wizard</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">king</div>
  <div class="square">bank</div>
  <div class="square">EARTH</div>
  <div class="square">guardian</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <h1 class="board">STORIE</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function that validates the limits you need. I leave you an example of how it would be: In this case if it is in position 0,0 it makes an alert

```js
var dice = document.getElementById("dice").addEventListener("click", numChange);

function numChange() {
  alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1));
}


let circle = document.querySelector(".man");
let moveBy = 25;

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  circle.style.position = "absolute";
  circle.style.left = 0;
  circle.style.top = 0;
});

function verifyPosition(circleLeftPosition,circleRightPosition, moveBy ){
  console.log(circleLeftPosition, circleRightPosition )
  if(circleLeftPosition =='0px' && circleRightPosition=='0px'){
    alert('INVALID POSITION')
    //ADDED YOUR LIMITS!
  }
}
window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
    verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy)
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
    verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy)
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
    verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy)
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
     verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy)
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.board {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  //grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 10vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 10vw);
  color: grey;
  background-color: grey;
  font-family: Dosis, sans-serif;
}

.link {
  font-family: Dosis, san-serif;
}

* {
  font-family: "Dosis", "san-serif";
}

.square:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.square:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.square:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.square:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.square:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.square:nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.square:nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.square:nth-child(12) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.square:nth-child(13) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.square:nth-child(14) {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.square:nth-child(15) {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 1;
  }

.square:nth-child(16) {
    //grid-row: 2;
    //grid-column: 1;
  }

 Demo Specific Style
.board {
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.square {
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.man {
  position: absolute;
  top: 410px;
  right: 380px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black; 
}
/* .man2 {  */ 
  position: absolute;
  top: 410px;
  right: 545px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: up 9s infinite;
  animation-delay: 8.5s;
}
 .man3 { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 545px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: right2 9s infinite;
  animation-delay: 17s;
}


@keyframes right {
  from {right: 240px;}
  to {right: 540px;}
  0% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  75% {
 
    background-color: black;
  }
  100%{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
  }
  }


  


.dice {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 440px;
  top: 320px;
}

numChange {
  
}
/*.inside-board {*/
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 145px;
  right: 290px;
}
```

```html
<div class="man"></div.
<div class="man2" id="seen"></div>
<div class="man3" id="Seen"></div>
<div class="dice" id="dice"></div>
<div class="inside-board"></div>

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="https://cdpn.io/Dims09/debug/mdOXGrQ/xnMabmBRoVjr">
  <h3 class="link">Back</h3>
</a>
<div class="board">
  
  <div class="square">START</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">guardian</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">LAVA</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">NATIVE</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">wizard</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <div class="square">king</div>
  <div class="square">bank</div>
  <div class="square">EARTH</div>
  <div class="square">guardian</div>
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <h1 class="board">STORIE</h1>
```

Comment: Your code should works fine, but `verifyPosition() ` can be called only one time, and should be after the positionning, or it will not trigger at the first crossing without pressing an arrow again. It can be after the switch.